# Options to extract/export existing azure resources into HCL files

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a comprehensive, existing and working azure resources that I need to create terraform HCL scripts that deploy them in many another environments.

I like to avoid hand-coding all resources.

Is there any way to automatically (or semi automatically) generate .HCL files based on resources in an Azure resource group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a method to automatically generate HCL files based on resources in an Azure resource group. [Here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1115) is a similar feature request for the Azure template to terraform `.tf` file converter.

You need to import existing infrastructure into your Terraform state. If you only need to extract some attributes of existing resources, you can use this [Data Source: azurerm_resources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/resources) to access information about existing resources.

Answer (score 0):

you can use aztfexport. I have written a detailed post about the same https://wellytonian.com/posts/cloud/tfexportdev/ . This will help build you TF deployment files, and if required also a local tf state file. However recommend to put your state file up on AZ blob or TF Cloud.

#azure #terraform #import #state